# Rosmake takes too long

Tags: ros, rosmake, compilation, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am used to compile with Makefiles and with the help of pkg-configs, where compilation time is usually under a second.

However, when I have to include some ROS stuff into my project I usually have to create a new ros pkg to be able to compile it (using rosmake). I can't just include it on my Makefile because there is not a pkg-config available for some components (move_base_msgs for example).

The problem is that when compiling with rosmake it usually takes over 10 seconds and some times it is even close to 20 seconds. This happens with simple projects with few dependencies such as these three:

Is there a way to reduce compilation time with rosmake? or to call some libraries from my own (and faster) Makefile? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51579/rosmake-takes-too-long/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake is a wrapper around make, it basically parses the manifest.xml, builds a dependency tree of projects, and for each project invokes make. This allows convenient invocation of make in many projects spread around the filesystem.

If you want to just build one project however, you can just as well call

```
$ roscd someproject
$ make
```

Typical ROS projects use only a small makefile that invokes cmake, but you are free to use other Makefiles. However with the typical ROS cmake approach, you get the benefit of convenience macros e.g. for message generation.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-01-07**:
Thanks for the tip, yet, using make in the project folter takes around 7 seconds vs 11 seconds using rosmake someproject. It is still a bit far from my expectations

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use rospack to get the needed compile flags inside your makefile. Note, normally there is a big bunch of include paths, that are responsible for the long lasting compilation time.

---

Originally posted by [2_socke](https://answers.ros.org/users/996/2_socke/) with karma: 76 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-01-07**:
Interesting, I guess that I just have to use rospack as if it were pkg-config for example:
rospack cflags-only-I move_base_msgs
rospack libs-only-l move_base_msgs